# how to render select tag inside php

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi i have this select tag in html that i want to put inside php tag my problem is in the views the select tag wont render this is my code below.
This is my controller

```
function rotating_banners(){

        $this->rapyd->load("datagrid");

        // grid
        $grid                   = new DataGrid("", "banner_rotating");


        $grid->per_page         = 50;
        $grid->num_links        = 2;


        $grid->column_orderby(  "Image"
                                ,"<img src=\"uploads/banners/<#br_filename#>\" height=\"60\" alt=\"\" />"
                                ,"bt_filename");




        $grid->column("Active?", "br_active", "br_active");

        $grid->column("Select", "<select name='banner'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select>");


        $save_link = anchor(
                                "banners/rotating_banner_crud/save/<#br_id#>",
                                "save",
                                "title='save'"
                            );


        $edit_link              = anchor(
                                        "banners/rotating_banner_crud/modify/<#br_id#>"
                                        ,"edit"
                                        ,"title='Edit this banner'"
                                        );

        $delete_link            = anchor(
                                        "banners/rotating_banner_crud/delete/<#br_id#>"
                                        ,"delete"
                                        ,"title='Delete this banner'"
                                        );

        $grid->column("Actions", "$save_link - $edit_link - $delete_link", "width=\"150\"");

        $grid->add("banners/rotating_banner_crud/create");

        $grid->build();


        $_arrPage_data          = Array(
                                        "cat_nav_list"      => $this->Category_model->build_category_navigation("", true)
                                        ,"rapyd_head"       => $this->rapyd->get_head()
                                        ,"output"           => $grid->output
                                        );


        $this->load->view('admin/rotating_banners', $_arrPage_data);
    }



$grid->column("Select", "<select name='banner'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select>");
```

How can i add the select tag inside the php? im using codeigniter

Any help is muchly appreciated TIA

Comment: So you just want a `<select>` tag in php tags?

Comment: yes i want that the select when i see in brower will render the select options

Comment: How you passing this `$grid` to your view? Your Select tag is correct, you should somehow pass this variable/object to your view and echo it.

Comment: its only this 
<?=$output?>

Comment: im just fixing some issues on it the output in the views is only this
<?=$output?>

Comment: @androidapple it would be best if you could share the controller function where your this code is and view code.

Comment: ok ill edit my code above

Comment: im updating my code above

Comment: why are you adding to grid after you build grid? Seems like a simple sequence problem

Comment: what you mean @charlietfl ???

Comment: I mean line at end `$grid->column("Select"` comes after you call `build` and after you load view

Comment: what you mean line at end?

Comment: end of your code...what do you think it would mean?

Comment: this is the render output in the page
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0594szu056